# What's difference of multiply insert methods in peewee for insert some data in to sqlite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, peewee

recently, I saw that there were three ways to insert data into sqlite using peewee, I know the speed among them is not the same, but is there any reason for the existence of the slowest method?

```
cls.create(...)
```

And the another two ways are:

```
with db.atomic():
    for data in data_to_insert:
        cls.create(**data)
```

```
with db.atomic():
    cls.insert_many(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many times, users want a simple API. So `create()` is provided. Behind-the-scenes, this delegates to a `insert()` call.

Databases can optimize inserting many rows, so there are APIs for bulk insertion as well.

It is about providing a balance between making simple things easy, and making more complicated things possible.